# How can my app change the network to another WiFi in android 6.0 mobilephone?

Tags: android

Process as below (Test on platform android api level =23 an android 6.0 mobilephone):

1. In my app i do as :

   ```
   mWifiManager.addNetwork(wcg);
   boolean b = mWifiManager.enableNetwork(wcgID, true);
   ```

   but b always return false;

   log print:

   ```
   Not authorized to remove network 
   ......
   Not authorized to update network
   ```
2. Then I  try the a Method in the WifiManager(Marked @Hide):

   ```
   connect(int networkId, ActionListener listener)
   ```

   by reflectMethod , the result was also failed . Print as:

   ```
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   ```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a legitimate case.

Check [WifiStateMachine](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/807f6a8502cc35bd250b903e2315bcdc34c49a92/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java) code, particularly `recordUidIfAuthorized` (line 454) which is being used by all the remove or update calls.

If I'm reading this right, not everyone is authorized to modify or remove network configurations. You would have to be an owner of that configuration (= this configuration would have to be submitted by your process in the first place) to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

In Lollipop you should try checking active ssid is same otherwise disable the network.

```
 int netId = mWifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
if (netId == -1) {
                    Log.d(this, "Failed to set the settings for  " + mNetworkSsidToConnect);
                    final List<WifiConfiguration> mWifiConfiguration = mWifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mWifiConfiguration.size(); i++) {
                        String configSSID = mWifiConfiguration.get(i).SSID;
                        Log.d(this, "Config SSID" + configSSID + "Active SSID" + conf.SSID);
                        netId = mWifiConfiguration.get(i).networkId;
                        if (configSSID.equals(conf.SSID)) {
                            Log.d(this, "network id" + netId);
                            break;
                        } else {
            **/*If SSID is not same disable other network here */**
                            mWifiManager.disableNetwork(netId);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Sincerely thank you for your advise, but the problem  i met was happened in marshmallow. I know there are some changes between marshmallow and Lollipop even lower android sdk version. So, how can i app change the wifi from one to another successfully  is my problem .

Comment: In Marshmallow you should give permission like location etc to get ScanResult. then WifiManager to connect to specific AP.